# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' error in dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, postman, decode

I have tried to decode a json file which is coming back from server after my request, but when i want to decode the json it show an error
here is my decode codes:

```
 var loginJson = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
      var model = idResponseModel(
          loginJson['id'],
          loginJson["fname"],
          loginJson["lname"],
          loginJson["nationalCode"],
          loginJson["gender"],
          loginJson["bornDate"],
          loginJson["phoneNumber"],
          loginJson["cardNumber"],
          loginJson["enabled"]);
      print(model.id);
```

and console says it happened in **loginJson['id']**

the **id** from server is some thing like this :

```
"id": "5de0a41e-9a6f-4b55-9567-024cd0fdbfc5"
```

Comment: And what is first parameter of idResponseModel? String? No? So what you expected?

Comment: @Selvin I know i changed first parameter to int too but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

slightly surprised by the direct use of [bodyBytes] try using the Response getter → body

```
String get body => _encodingForHeaders(headers).decode(bodyBytes);
```

in your case it should look like this:

```
var loginJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var model = idResponseModel(
          loginJson['id'],
          loginJson["fname"],
          loginJson["lname"],
          loginJson["nationalCode"],
          loginJson["gender"],
          loginJson["bornDate"],
          loginJson["phoneNumber"],
          loginJson["cardNumber"],
          loginJson["enabled"]);
      print(model.id);
```

I have no way to check it now but if it works let me know

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `loginJson.[]` expects an int, not a String. So it's possible that `loginJson` is actually a List, and not a Map like you expect it to be. You can check by printing `loginJson.runtimeType`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you'd post the whole JSON, this question is insufficient and not reproducible... because you might believe you have the response already, while trying to get data from the wrong one node (`id` is a string index, but it encounters an unexpected numeric index). That's exactly why your sample data and the error message do not provide the least meaning in combination.